# How to alter the filename of a reportlab canvas object?

Tags: python, reportlab

If a `reportlab.pdfgen.canvas` object is created it is given a filename:

```
c = canvas.Canvas('test.pdf', pagesize=A4)
```

How can I alter this filename afterwards before I call

```
c.save()
```

There is a member `_filename` accessible in class `Canvas` and to alter it will do the trick. But, is there a better way?